# Set pygtk window name on Wayland

Tags: python, pygtk

On x11 I can set the name of my application with

```
self.set_wmclass ("Name", "Name")
```

So that When I launch it with a .desktop file it keeps the icon and is called "Name" instead of main.py

But that doesn't work on wayland. I'm unable to find anything by googling

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`GLib.set_prgname('app_name')`

The `app_name` must correspond to a `exec=` in `.desktop` file, then the `name=` from the `.desktop` file will be used.

I'm not sure if it is the right syntax for pygtk though.

Answer (score 0):

Not confirmed on Wayland, but `self.set_title("Foobar")` should work. ([source](https://valadoc.org/gtk4/Gtk.Window.set_title.html))